# How to programmatically send an email?

Tags: 7, emails

I'd like to use Drupal's email system to programmatically send an email from my custom module. Is that possible?

Comment: this question is linked to: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84268/use-hook-cron-to-send-daily-mail-but-i-get-45-the-same-mail-every-day

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Using [hook_mail](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_mail/7) and [drupal_mail](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7) you can create and send an e-mail.

Implement an e-mail use hook_mail:

```
function MODULENAME_mail ($key, &$message, $params) {
  switch ($key) {
    case 'mymail':
      // Set headers etc
      $message['to'] = 'foo@bar.com';
      $message['subject'] = t('Hello');
      $message['body'][] = t('Hello @username,', array('@username' => $params['username']));
      $message['body'][] = t('The main part of the message.');
      break;
  }
}
```

To send a mail use drupal_mail:

```
drupal_mail($module, $key, $to, $language, $params = array('username' => 'John Potato'), $from = NULL, $send = TRUE)
```

Obviously replace the parameters: $key should equal 'mymail'

An e-mail is sent in a few steps:

1. drupal_mail is called
2. Drupal builds the e-mail
3. hook_mail is called for the specifics (implementation)
4. hook_mail_alter is called so other modules can modify it
5. drupal_send_mail is called

Comment: He's right, but to clarify a bit hook_mail provides you with a way to structure and theme an email based on an arbitrary key that you define. drupal_mail() is what you call to send an email. Pass the key for the structure you'd like to use. (and the module that responds to that key)

Comment: In this example `$message['to']` is hard coded to `foo@bar.com`. Omit this and the message will be sent to the recipient that is specified when `drupal_mail()` is called.

Comment: This solution is deprecated.

Answer (score 14):

If you'd like a simpler way of sending emails, check out [Simple Mail](https://drupal.org/project/simple_mail); it's a module I'm working on to make sending emails with Drupal 7+ much easier, and it doesn't require any extra hook implementations or MailSystem knowledge. Sending an email is as simple as:

```
simple_mail_send($from, $to, $subject, $message);
```

Comment: ...and it works with Drupal 8, too, with the exact same API :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simpler way of sending emails, check out [mailsystem](https://drupal.org/project/mailsystem) ; it's a module.

```
<?php
$my_module = 'foo';
$from = variable_get('system_mail', 'organization@example.com');
$message = array(
  'id' => $my_module,
  'from' => $from,
  'to' => 'test@example.com',
  'subject' => 'test',
  'body' => 'test',
  'headers' => array(
    'From' => $from, 
    'Sender' => $from, 
    'Return-Path' => $from,
  ),
);

$system = drupal_mail_system($my_module, $my_mail_token);
if ($system->mail($message)) {
  // Success.
}
else {
  // Failure.
}
?>
```

Comment: Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in a hook of your own choice within your custom module:

```
 function yourmodulename_mail($from = 'default_from', $to, $subject, $message) {
            $my_module = 'yourmodulename';
            $my_mail_token = microtime();
            if ($from == 'default_from') {
                // Change this to your own default 'from' email address.
                $from = variable_get('system_mail', 'admin@yoursite.com');
            }
            $message = array(
                'id' => $my_module . '_' . $my_mail_token,
                'to' => $to,
                'subject' => $subject,
                'body' => array($message),
                'headers' => array(
                    'From' => $from,
                    'Sender' => $from,
                    'Return-Path' => $from,
                ),
            );
            $system = drupal_mail_system($my_module, $my_mail_token);
            $message = $system->format($message);
            if ($system->mail($message)) {
                return TRUE;
            } else {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
```

Then you can use the above function like this:

```
        $user = user_load($userid); // load a user using its uid
        $usermail = (string) $user->mail; // load user email to send a mail to it OR you can specify an email here to which the email will be sent 
        customdraw_mail('default_from', $usermail, 'You Have Won a Draw -- this is the subject',  'Congrats! You have won a draw --this is the body');
```