# Drupal says "e-mail sent" but I don't receive

Tags: 7, emails

I have installed my webserver from a computer at home. On Ubuntu Server, LAMP, everything works fine except email sending.

First I was getting:

> Unable to send email

then I followed [these directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224161/unable-to-send-e-mail-please-contact-the-site-administrator-if-the-problem-pers).

Then I still got same error. I checked Apache logs and I found

```
sendmail: fatal: file /etc/postfix/main.cf: parameter myhostname: bad parameter value: myservername.{null}
```

I changed the file and wrote my website domain like domain.com

At last, Drupal says "Email sent" but I receive no email. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you used a devel php input to do a sendmail test?
there is a question already answered here.
[How to programmatically send an email?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6677/how-to-programmatically-send-an-email)

Also here is a great article on debugging emails...
http://www.drupalcoder.com/blog/how-to-debug-outgoing-mails-in-drupal