# How to get notified when a user is blocked?

Tags: hooks, users, blocks

Is there a way to get notified when a user is blocked ? like a hook in user module or ? or there are another way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [hook_user_update()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_update/7%20%22hook_user_update%28%29) for this. Below is an example on how you can use it for your purpose:

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_user_update().
 */
function my_module_user_update(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  // Check if the user was blocked
  if ($account->original->status != $account->status && $account->status == 0) {
    // Handle notification here
  }
}
```

To send an email programmatically from Drupal, you can check out [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6677/how-to-programmatically-send-an-email).

**Another way to do this**, would be by using the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module and following the steps below:

1. Create a new rule that reacts on the user event "After updating an existing user account".
2. Add a condition of type "User is blocked" and save it with the defaults.
3. Add another condition of type "User is blocked", but this time use "account-unchanged" for the **Data Selector** and check the **Negate** checkbox.
4. Add an action of type System > "Send mail" and play with it.

Comment: That is good, But this hook is going to be called when ever any user changes any thing, Is there a hook doing that ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question ... but yes, this hook gets called every time a user account gets updated (either by users or administrators).

Comment: I just added an alternative solution. This one involves using the Rules module and you don't need to write any code to use it.

Comment: That restrict your action for just sending email. but the first is much powerful.

Comment: You are not restricted at all. There are more actions you can use and if they are not sufficient, you can always use PHP code as an action (you need to have PHP filter enabled first).

Answer (score 0):

There are function - [user_is_blocked($name)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_is_blocked/7). Where do you want to notify user?

But you can simply check user name like this:

```
  if (user_is_blocked($user->name) != FALSE) {
       drupal_set_message('account blocked');
  }
```

To notify user when account is blocked you can go to `admin/config/people/accounts` there are tab - `Account blocked` - and you can check `Notify user when account is blocked.` You can set subject and body.

Comment: Okay I meant when the user get blocked by an administrator I get notified ?

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: I mean that when any user get blocked I as a developer get notified by hook or any other mean ?