# How to to check if user has changed the password?

Tags: 7, users, rules

I wanted to send basic notification email to the user, after it has changed the password, to inform him of password change.

I am using `Rules` modules for that. But I am not finding any option there, to add condition if user has changed the password.

Is there any way I can check if user has changed his password using rules or pragmatically.

-- Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Check this may help you http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/68380/how-to-get-notified-when-a-user-is-blocked/68389?noredirect=1#68389

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest would be to do this using Rules. Following the next steps, should do the job.

1. Ensure you have enabled the "PHP filter" on the modules page. This is needed to be able to use PHP code inside Rules.
2. Create a rule that reacts on the user event "After saving a new user account".
3. Add a condition of type "Execute custom PHP code" and use the following snippet: 
   `return $account_unchanged->pass != $account->pass;`
4. Add your action(s) to send an email notification to the user or anything else that fits your purpose.

Comment: have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I tested this out just before I wrote the answer.

Comment: Thanks, simple and efficient solution. Works like charm!!

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tried it in Rules before, but it would probably be a matter of comparing values on the `$account` and `$account->original` objects.

One way to do it in custom code is to implement [`hook_user_presave()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_presave/7):

```
function MYMODULE_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  // Don't show message for registering users.
  if (isset($account->is_new) && $account->is_new) {
    return;
  }

  if (!empty($edit['pass']) && $account->pass != $edit['pass']) {
    // Password has been changed.
  }
}
```

You could probably do the same in `hook_user_update()`, but I haven't tried that before. The above is taken from a live project and works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Using Rules might be easier since you are already using it, but you need to enable **PHP Filter** module.

The instructions as follow:

1. Enable PHP Filter module `admin/modules`
2. Create a new Rule `admin/config/workflow/rules`
3. Make sure to select `After updating an existing user account` from React on event dropdow list.
4. Add a condition and choose `Execute custom PHP code`
5. Add the following PHP custom code in the value section

   `if(!empty($account->current_pass)) {
     return true;
   }`
6. Then add an action and select `Send mail`
7. In the value section add `[account:mail]` and fill subject field and message field.