# E-mail results from page callback

Tags: rules, emails, routes

I have a menu hook and page callback which takes several arguments to generate some table data in a page, the page makes heavy use of entityfield_query and some other modules.

I need to be able to e-mail the contents of this page based on a set of periodic dates. What's the best way to achieve this?

I realise that the css will all have to be added to the page but if I could get the structure into an e-mail that would be a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [drupal_mail()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7) together with [hook_mail()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail/7) to send email.

See also the [Examples for Developers](https://drupal.org/project/examples).

Comment: This works for sending email but it does not answer how I can do this periodically, I need to do it based on a financial calendar which I have stored elsewhere.

Comment: @DanielHarper if you need to run periodic tasks, use `hook_cron`

Comment: But cron runs every hr and I don't want the e-mail to send every hr just once on a specific set of days.

Comment: Check the day in hook_cron and send if needed.

Comment: So then it would run every hour of that day, I guess I would check whether it is a specific hour as well

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link with full detailed explanation on how to send and edit the contents.

[How to programmatically send an email?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6677/how-to-programmatically-send-an-email)

Comment: While this could answer the question, it is better to expand the answer with a summary of what reported in the linked page. Stack Exchange sites don't aim to be a repository of links, but a repository of knowledge.