# Configuring mail function in multistep form submission handler

Tags: 7, commerce, emails, forms

I have been working in a [multistep customer-survey form](http://test-site.davidsonj.com/customer-survey) and i am unable to configure and send mail after the form is successfully submitted.

Here's is code for submit handler,

```
function customer_survey_personal_details_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $multstep_values = $form_state['multistep_values'];

  $module = 'customer_survey';
  $key = 'customer_survey_complete';

  $to = $multstep_values['personal_details']['email'] . '; ' . variable_get('site_mail', 'admin@example.com');
  $from = variable_get('site_mail', 'admin@example.com');

  $params = array(
    'body' => 'Thank you for filling in our survey. You have now been entered into our prize draw.',
    'subject' => 'Thank you for filling in our survey, ' . $multstep_values['personal_details']['name'],  
  );

  $language = language_default();
  $send = TRUE;
  $result = drupal_mail($module, $key, $to, $language, $params, $from, $send);
  if ($result['result'] == TRUE) {
    drupal_set_message(t('Your message has been sent.'));
  }
  else {
    drupal_set_message(t('There was a problem sending your message and it was not sent.'), 'error');
  }       
}
```

I did configure my mail address in the `$from` variable but it didn't worked.

I am able to send email from other modules.

What could be the problem?

Can someone suggest me a possible solution?

[image: Error message]

**UPDATE:**

Thanks @Mołot for the `dpr($result);`. I found that the problem resides with my `$to` variable.If i explicitly give the recipient email address, the mail is sent successfully..

It will be helpful if someone could say what is the problem in this line of code,

```
$to = $multstep_values['personal_details']['email'] . '; ' . variable_get('site_mail', 'admin@example.com');
```

I replaced recipient mail address instead of `admin@example.com`. But it didn't work.

Comment: You should call [hook_mail()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail/7) function for it and enter the message, body and all other parameters inside it.
drupal_mail() calls hook_mail() Check this link : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6677/how-to-programmatically-send-an-email

Comment: the hook_mail() function is already implemented in the module already..but its not working..

Comment: possible duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6677/how-to-programmatically-send-an-email

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically send an email?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6677/how-to-programmatically-send-an-email)

Comment: I guess your server in not working properly or it is not configured properly. Try to configure the Server properly and it would work properly.

Comment: if my server not configured properly..then how would the email functionality work in other modules..but not this one..?

Comment: @harshal this question is probably not the duplicate of the above question..here i have all the necessary implementation required for sending an email from a module(which is also suggested in the other question)..but the code doesn't work..

Comment: @Lucky apparently you *don't* have "all the necessary implementation required for sending an email". What does your watchdog says about it? What's in system logs? What's the output of `dpr($result);`? Without that information we cannot help you. Also, drupal_mail expect you to implement hook_mail, and it seems you didn't so marking as duplicate seems justified.

Comment: @Mołot i tried using `dpr($result)`..and it was showing this `Invalid address: FROMADDRESS@gmail.com; TOADDRESS@gmail.com You must provide at least one recipient email address..so i changed the $from and $to email address in the code above explicitly..and now it is working..what could be the problem in the $from and $to variables..