# How to send an email to the admin when user fails to login?

Tags: 7, forms, users, rules, hooks

I need to implement the functionality to notify the admin user via email whenever someone fails to login entering wrong password. Basically simple email format containing the username for failed account to login. Can someone give guidance or suggestion?

P.S: I checked the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module but it doesn't have required Rules event like "*When user fails to login*".

Comment: so... how did it go?

Comment: @No Sssweat: Your suggestion was quick and easy implementation, however i needed exact requirement functionality, i.e. send email on first failed login, also capture username and time. Hence, i created custom module utilizing user_authenticate() - to check if login/pass match inside my custom form validation and simply triggered drupal_mail() when user_authenticate()=false.

Answer (score 2):

People mistype or use wrong alternate passwords all the time. Would be overkill to send e-mail on a first failed attempt.

**For security reasons, Drupal blocks user account after 5 login failed attempts.**

You can use [Rules Block/Unblock User](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_block_user) to send e-mail when user gets blocked. (failed 5 times)

> This module adds rules events, as well as some default rules, for when
>   a user account is blocked or unblocked.
>
> [image]

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens can't remember, but either back in the day DA allowed drupal.org .png files to be imported OR I did a copy paste to an image editing program then saved to my hard drive and uploaded it.

Comment: hm, that sounds like what I was guessing also, so merci!

Answer (score 1):

You can send mail only those user to whom has an data against the user name provided on login time. You can send mail using `hook_mail`. 
So on user login time you have to validate the data.

> 1. define a validation function using `form alter()`.
> 2. validate user authentication ([how to validate](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_login_authenticate_validate/7.x/))
> 3. if fail fetch user data and call `drupal_mail` function [more info](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6677/how-to-programmatically-send-an-email).

I hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks! your guidance was helpful. I implemented custom validation function which uses !user_authenticate() and drupal_mail() with hook_mail()

Comment: Welcome .....:)